# How do I automatically choose "No" when Remove-Item prompts for confirmation?

Tags: powershell

When using PowerShell's `Remove-Item` to remove a directory that is not empty, it will prompt for confirmation:

```
PS C:\Users\<redacted>\Desktop\Temp> Remove-Item .\Test

Confirm
The item at C:\Users\<redacted>\Desktop\Temp\Test has children and the Recurse parameter was not specified. If you
continue, all children will be removed with the item. Are you sure you want to continue?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
```

If I run powershell in non-interactive mode, I get an error instead:

```
Remove-Item : Windows PowerShell is in NonInteractive mode. Read and Prompt functionality is not available.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-Item .\Test
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Remove-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

I know that I can use `-Recurse` to have `Remove-Item` proceed as if I had chosen the "Yes" option. Can I somehow proceed as if I had chosen the "No" option?

(Just for clarity: `-Force` and `-Confirm:$false` are not what I want here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO the correct answer is to set the -ErrorAction to SilentlyContinue. Then you don't have to have empty try-catch code.

Like this:

```
PS C:\Users\<redacted>\Desktop\Temp> Remove-Item .\Test -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

UPDATE: 06-26-2023
PowerShell 7 changed this behavior as @Destroy666 pointed out. You can use the [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.3#ternary-operator--if-true--if-false) in PoSH 7 to still make it a one liner and avoid empty try catch blocks.

```
function TestIt () {
    $myFolder = 'C:\MyTestFolder'
    New-Item -Path $myFolder -ItemType Directory
    Set-Content -Path $myFolder\myfile.txt -Value 'My test text content'
    (Test-Path -Path $myFolder\*.*) ? $null : (Remove-Item -Path $myFolder)

    Get-ChildItem -Path $myFolder
}

TestIt
```

Running this gives the results:

```
PS C:\> . .\test.ps1

    Directory: C:\

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d----           6/26/2023  6:28 PM                MyTestFolder

    Directory: C:\MyTestFolder

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---           6/26/2023  6:28 PM             22 myfile.txt

PS C:\>
```

Comment: This doesn't work in PowerShell 7.

Comment: @Destroy666 Looks like they changed the behavior. Updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use test-path to determine if the directory is empty before you try to delete it:

```
if (-not (Test-Path .\Test\*.*))
  { Try 
     { Remove-Item .\Test -ErrorAction Stop }
    Catch { Continue }
  }
```

The Try Catch will handle any errors

Comment: Yes, I could test the directory before trying to remove it. However, that would generate a race condition if a file was added to the directory between the test and the Remove-Item invocation. In all situations, I want the script to just continue executing even if it couldn't delete the folder.

Comment: Updated for additional requirements.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.  The files do not get removed and the script proceeds on.  You still see the error about NonInteractive mode, but the command moves on as if No was answered.

```
remove-item c:\test\test

Write-host "Files are still there, script still going"
```

If you just want to suppress that error message wrap it in a Try\Catch

```
Try
{
remove-item c:\test\test 
}
Catch
{

}

Write-host "Files are still there, script still going"
```

Comment: I don't want the error message about non-interactive mode to be displayed, so I'll choose your second option. Thinking about it, catching the exception thrown by Remove-Item is probably the way to go anyway. (It's only strange that the exception message is complaining about non-interactive mode, not about an undeletable folder.)